# How to modify web2py download function to return "304 Not Modified" in case the file did not change?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

In my case i have a database with document thumbnails that are displayed on an overview page. Every time the browser visits the site all thumbnail images are downloaded again and so the download function loads again all the images from the database. Since i am running on GAE this drives up my database-reads enormous.

I tried to enable client site caching by setting:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def download():
  response.headers['Cache-Control'] = None
  response.headers['Pragma'] = None
  response.headers['Expires'] = None
  return response.download(request, db)
```

I also read that response.stream may help but the web2py book says:

> As noted above, response.download should be used to retrieve files stored via an upload field. response.stream can be used in other cases, such as returning a temporary file or StringIO object created by the controller.

#### -- EDIT --

I got the client side caching enabled with:

```
session.forget() #important
expire_time = datetime.timedelta(days=2)

response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'private, max-age%d'%(60*60*24*2)
response.headers['Pragma'] = None
response.headers['Expires'] = (request.utcnow + expire_time).strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = \
      'attachment;filename=' + filename + ';'

return response.stream(stream, filename=filename)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if the images are publicly available and do not require authentication to view, then instead of storing them in the /uploads folder, you can store them in the /static folder and then simply serve them as static files. In that case, the headers will be set automatically for client side caching (it will also be faster and more efficient).

Second, you can use `response.stream()` to stream uploaded files, but it won't automatically identify the folder where the file is located nor decode the original filename from the encoded filename and add it to the Content-Disposition header (which you don't need in this case anyway because you are displaying the images and not downloading them). So, as long as you pass the full file path to `response.stream()`, you should be able to use it in this case, and it will set the response headers appropriately for caching.

Finally, if you want to set the response headers directly, it would be something like:

```
import os
import time
modified = os.stat(file)[stat.ST_MTIME]
mtime = time.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT', time.gmtime(modified))
response.headers['Last-Modified'] = mtime
response.headers['Pragma'] = 'cache'
response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'private'
```

Comment: I cannot store the images directly in the static folcer because:
1. the application runs on Google App Engine.
2. the files require authentication.

I will try my luck with your second proposal

Comment: I tried it with:
`response.headers['Content-Type']  = 'image/jpeg'`,
`response.headers['Pragma']        = 'cache'`,
`response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'private'` and
    
`return response.stream(stream, filename=filename)`

but the server does not respond with 304, what am i missing?

Comment: Sorry, forgot you mentioned you were on GAE. Did you set the Last-Modified header as well?

Comment: ok, first thing i realized is that i have to use `session.forget()`. Otherwise (gae or web2py?) will set the `Expire` header to the the current time due to a present `Set-Cookie` header. That's because of a security issue with some proxies.[related issue Ticket](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2106). 

And yes i also set the `Last-Modified` header before. I'll post more details when i get it working

Comment: I had a look at the source of response.stream and for me it seems that `stream_file_or_304_or_206` is executed only if the stream is a str -> a file on the file system. That makes sense in a way because otherwise the system has no information when the file was modified last. A workaround would be to add a add 'last-modified' field to the table and check for it manually before calling response.stream and if last-modified equals the database value raise the 304 Exception. But since that would also require database querys it doesn't solve my problem. I'll update your answer to my working solution

Answer (score 0):

If you serve images, why not use Google High Performance Image serving. Using this API (get_serving_url) Google will serve the images for you. You do not need a handler! It is fast, you can resize, and it only costs you some bandwith.

But this works only for images. Here is some of my code to serve a CSS from the blobstore including the 304.

```
class DynCSS(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):

    def get(self, resource):                                        

        (key, _, _) = resource.rpartition('.')
        self.response.headers[str('ETag')] = str(key)
        if 'If-None-Match' in self.request.headers:
            etags = [x.strip()
                     for x in self.request.headers[str('If-None-Match')].split(',')]
            if key in etags:
                self.response.set_status(304) # optimize traffic 304
                return
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(key) 
        self.send_blob(blob_info, save_as=True)
```

The resource argument is a blob_key with .css added. And I use unicode literals.

High Performance Image Serving uses : get_serving_url https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions

Example :

```
entity.serving_url = images.get_serving_url(entity.blob_key, size=None, secure_url=True)
```

How to use :

- Upload your image to your blobstore
- Save the blob_key with your image file_name in the datastore
- Create a get_serving_url. You only have to create it once.
- Use serving urls in your template img tags.

A serving_url looks like this : https://lh6.ggpht.com/lOghqU2JrYk8M-Aoio8WjMM6mstgZcTP0VzJk79HteVLhnwZy0kqbgVGQZYP8YsoqVNzsu0EBysX16qMJe7H2BsOAr4j=s70

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Google High Performance Image API documentation?